# Django: Get all objects and the first record of a related model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

Initially I was just grabbing all `camera` models:

```
cameras = Camera.objects.all()
return render(request, 'myapp/cameras.html', {'content': cameras})
```

But I now need to also include the latest record of `CameraLog` for each `Camera` that is called in the statement above. `CameraLog` has a foreign key for the `Camera` it's associated with.

I need to pass these cameras to a view, so I need to be able to loop over not only the `Camera` data, but the `CameraLog` log as well.

I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm sure this is an easy modification for you guys...

```
cameras = Camera.objects.all( and also the latest CameraLog )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a model property like this .

```
class Camera(models.Model):
     fields = models.Fields()

     @property
     def last_log(self):
          return self.cameralog_set.first()
```

Now in your templates:

```
{% for camera in cameras %}
    #show camera info
    {{ camera.last_log }}
    # show camera log info

{% endfor %}
```

You can also use prefetch_related and use django Prefetch() to specify queryset to do this very optimally.

Comment: I like this idea, for sure. The inner loop doesn't look complete?

Comment: There is no inner loop. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the following:

```
cameras = Camera.objects.all()
last_logs = [camera.cameralog_set.last for camera in cameras]
```

In other words your Camera's CameraLog(s) are already set, and you access to them using `cameralog_set` attribute.

Remember that you can access to related fields using `<relatedfieldname>_set` and to all elements with `.all()`, the first with `.first()` and the last with `.last()`

**UPDATE**

From your template you can do exactly the same

```
{% for camera in cameras %}
    #show camera info
    {% for log in camera.cameralog_set.all %}
        # show camera log info
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

So, you only need to pass the `cameras` variable to the template

Comment: Just updated my question. I need to be able to send a complete data set to a view to loop over.

Comment: with a view you mean a template (HTML) file?

Comment: Oh wow ... that's... incredible, actually. I had no idea. But can you use `.first` from the template as well?

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer due to an error (I wasn't adding the `.all` attribute). You can use `camera.cameralog_set.first` and `camera.cameralog_set.last` as well

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If you want to upvote it, also would be great. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting `'CameraLog' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get all cameralog related to a particular camera from that camera instance itself if you define your models well.

So for example, if you have your models defined like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Camera(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class CameraLogs(models.Model):
    cameralog = models.ForeignKey(
        Camera, related_name='cameralogs')
```

So, if you have a particular camera instance equal to camera, saying `camera.cameralogs.all()` should return all cameralogs belonging to that camera instance. You can read more on Django many-to-one relationships here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/